# How do i add multiple lines after a certain line in a text file using batch

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, edit

I need to edit a text file to insert multiple lines after a certain line with only features that come with windows 10

example: Insert the lines `foo` and `bar` after line 4

text file example before additions:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

text file example after additions:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
foo
bar
line 5
line 6
```

Comment: @Jeb, though I agree that this question is off topic and should probably be closed, the linked answer is horrible. No quoting of `set` lines and the answer does not cater for any empty lines.

Comment: @Gerhard You are right, the old answer isn't quite perfect. Feel free to add a better one :-)

Comment: @jeb, hmmm. I cannot really find a good answer. let me search more.

Comment: What is the rule for the line number for inserting? Is it a fixed number or a fixed search text?

Comment: @jeb the text should come after a certain line number, but the line number is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file and write it back, insert the new lines at a specific lineno.

```
@echo off

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set randomline=4
set "lineno=0"
(
    FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" sample.txt') do (
        set /a lineno+=1
        set "line=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion        
        if "!lineno!"=="%randomline%" call :insertblock
        set "line=!line:*:=!"
        (echo(!line!)
        endlocal
    )
) > output.txt
exit /b

:insertblock
echo foo
echo bar
exit /b
```

Comment: I might just be using it wrong but this is not working for me. it's outputting the same content in sample.txt as output.txt (without any edits). lineno was set to 5, sample.txt had more than 5 lines of text.

Comment: @guest257351 You saw that the output is in `output.txt` ?

Comment: okay sorry I was not using `randomline` correctly.